# Why this getchar() doesn't work properly?

Tags: c

Can anybody tell me why the line `o = getchar();` works properly only the first time and then once works, once it's not?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char o;

    for (int i = 1; i > 0; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", i);

        if (i % 10 == 0)
        {
            printf("Do you want to continue? (y/n): ");
            o = getchar();
            if (o == 'n')
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Jens or, just `#define EVER (;;)` and use `for EVER`... :)

Comment: After fixing the `char` -> `int` with `'o'`, to insure you do not skip a response, after `break;`, you can empty the input buffer of the remaining `'\n'` with `while ((o = getchar()) != '\n' && o != EOF) {}`.

Comment: An alternative to using `getchar` might be using `scanf` instead.  Also, `i++` eventually overflows which could either break `i > 0` or be optimized out by the compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, [`getchar()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar) returns an `int`, which may not fit into a `char`. Change

```
char o;
```

to

```
int o = 0;
```

Then, to come to the point of the *skipping*, well, it actually do not *skip*. When you press any key and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, the `newline` from the press of the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key serves as the feed to the `getchar()` in every second iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

As [Sourav Ghosh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34661418/1548311) stated, the problem is the newline character. Once you type something in the console and press "Enter" afterwards, the text is in the input buffer. This buffer is then read by `getchar`. However, `getchar` only reads *one* character with each call. The problem is, that "Enter" is interpreted as a character (`'\n'`) and is hold in the buffer, `getchar` is going to read it as an individual character. The next call of `getchar` will read the newline character, rather than the wanted character.

*Solution:* You could call `getchar` (after your actual call) until the newline is reached, thus clearing the read line inside the buffer.

```
while (getchar() != '\n')
    ;
```

Or just build a little function

```
int nextch() {
    int ch = getchar();
    while (getchar() != '\n')
        ;
    return ch;
}
```